# Lost polymorphism while assigning function to a variable inside a monad

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

**Background**

I'm trying to create a Parsec parser for numeric values. Those values can be either `Integer` or `Double`. They can also be signed or unsigned. I created a sign parser that returns polymorphic function `id` for `+` and `negate` for `-`. I also have a function that constructs proper version of my expression node, when given polymorphic sign function and `Either Integer Double`. I'm trying to put it all together as shown on simplified version of my code below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

-- (...)

data Expr = IntExpr Integer | DoubleExpr Double
pSign :: Num a => MyParser (a -> a) -- returns id for + or negate for -
pReal :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> Either Integer Double -> MyParser Expr

pNum :: MyParser Expr
pNum = do
    sign <- pSign
    numVal <- ParsecToken.naturalOrFloat lexer
    pReal sign numVal
```

I get a compilation error "Could not deduce (a ~ Integer) ..." when I use my code like above.

When I change my code by defining sign function inside a `let` statement in my monad, everything compiles fine:

```
pNum :: MyParser Expr
pNum = do
    sign <- pSign
    numVal <- ParsecToken.naturalOrFloat lexer
    let t = sign 1
        sign' :: Num a => a -> a
        sign' = if t == 1 then id else negate
    pReal sign numVal
```

My guess is that in the first case, polymophic type of `sign` is somehow lost and converted to `Integer -> Integer`.

**Question**

- What mechanism makes original `sign :: Num a => a -> a` monad variable not work as first argument of `pReal :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> ...`, while its redefined version of the same type (`sign'`) works?
- How can I achieve passing polymorphic variable `sign` created in my monad to `pReal` function without re-defining (`sign'`) it inside my monad?

**Notes**

I already tried approaches like explicitly defining type of `sign` with

```
pNum = pSign >>= \(sign :: Num a => a -> a) -> do ...
```

or the same with normal function definition etc.

Please note that I know that I can make the code easier by simply returning a boolean variable from `sign` instead of a polymorphic function. The point of this question is to understand how types work here.

Comment: In the future, it is polite to include a complete, compilable example -- including necessary imports, etc. Stubbing out unimportant things with `undefined` or similar is fine, just so long as I can dump it in my text editor and immediately start playing with it.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Thanks for the tip. I hadn't though about stubbing with `undefined`, so I included uncompilable version without definitions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You write

```
pSign :: Num a => MyParser (a -> a)
```

which means that `pSign` is a polymorphic value that, for any given instantiation of `a`, produces a parser containing a monomorphic function. Instead, you want a monomorphic parser containing a polymorphic function, so:

```
pSign :: MyParser (forall a. Num a => a -> a)
```

You will need to make a few other changes as well to get GHC to understand how to keep things polymorphic until the last second. Here is a complete, compilable example.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes, LiberalTypeSynonyms, RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

type MyParser = Parser

data Expr = IntExpr Integer | DoubleExpr Double
pSign :: MyParser (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -- returns id for + or negate for -
pReal :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> Either Integer Double -> MyParser Expr
foo :: MyParser (Either Integer Double)
pSign = undefined
pReal = undefined
foo = undefined

pNum :: MyParser Expr
pNum =
    pSign >>= \(sign :: forall a. Num a => a -> a) ->
    foo >>= \numVal ->
    pReal sign numVal
```

Comment: Also, it can be useful to go with newtypes here:  
`newtype NumOp = NumOp (Num a => a -> a)`  
`pSign :: MyParser NumOp`  
`pReal :: NumOp -> Either Integer Double -> MyParser Expr`  
`pNum = pSign >>= \(NumOp sign) -> ...`  
-- less typing, and no need in ImpredicativeTypes then!